# NSMutableURLRequest addValue method

Tags: swift, http

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```

So I have this piece of code and I'm struggling to understand what the addValue method does. I've read online about requests and HTTPHeaderFields but I still can't see to grasp the concept. Would anyone be able to shed some light on this?

Comment: If you don't know what a HTTP Header is then I'd suggest reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields and http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-headers-for-dummies--net-8039 and  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_header_fields.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addValue` adds an HTTP header to the receiver’s HTTP header dictionary.

This method provides the ability to add values to header fields incrementally. If a value was previously set for the specified field, the supplied value is appended to the existing value using the appropriate field delimiter. In the case of HTTP, the delimiter is a comma.

**Update**

HTTP header fields provide required information about the request or response, or about the object sent in the message body

You have added "Accept" in your addValue and the Accept request-header field can be used to specify certain media types which are acceptable for the response.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableURLRequest/addValue:forHTTPHeaderField:).

Comment: What is a header field?

Comment: HTTP header fields are components of the header section of request and response messages in theHTTP. They define the operating parameters of an HTTP transaction.

Comment: So when I add application/json to the header field I can think of it as telling the server what kind of information I want from it?